# Cordova Console Plugin console.log

Tags: xcode, cordova

This will hopefully be some easy SO points for someone...

### Goal: to see console.log statements in my xcode Debug Area

create the sample project from cordova (which contains an index.js file while logs the device ready event):

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello/
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git

cordova build ios
open platforms/ios/HelloWorld.xcodeproj
```

from within xcode: build/run (via the ▶ button)

output of xcode terminal:

```
Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
Unlimited access to network resources
Resetting plugins due to page load.
Finished load of: HelloWorld.app/www/index.html
```

Where are my `console.log()`'s?

---

cordova --version => 3.4.0-0.1.3

Comment: I followed your exact steps and it works.  What version of XCode are you using?

Comment: ah!  so frustrating.  I have xcode Version 5.0 (5A1413).  I will update to 5.1.1 and try again.  thanks @mmocny

Comment: I don't think that will solve the issue, I also use 5.0 and console plugin has worked for years.  Also note that cordova-ios just patched fixes for XCode 5.1 so if you do upgrade, also upgrade cordova to 3.4.1

Comment: I clearly have bigger problems.  when I `cordova run ios` and tail the output file, I see the same results as the xcode console.  (I also seriously regret updating xcode)

Comment: sorry for wasting everyone's time... this is working after a `cordova platform remove ios && cordova platform add ios && cordova plugin add ...`  thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can debug using the Safari to connect on your iphone. See this tutorial: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Comment: This won't solve the original issue -- but yes, using safari remote inspector is a superior way to debug webview applications in general.

Comment: The Console.log will write information on the NAVIGATOR console, not on Phonegap console. I don't even know if it's possible. I suggested what i think it's the better way to debug iOS =]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Renanlf, although I have never been able to get safari/ios simulator to play nicely.  Is there a way to keep it open so I can debug startup logs?  As it is now, I open developer tools and the console is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the `Debug Console plugin` installed.  You can install in through the CLI with `$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git`

Comment: just noticed you are installing the plugin